# C++ Builder: Date string is not converting correctly

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-11-alexandria

I am using Embarcadero C++ Builder Alexandria 11.1.

The `frmMain` form has a `TDatePicker dtpDate` used to select a date.

The selected date (`TDate`) value is converted to the `"yyyy-mm-dd"` format.

I need to convert the selected date value to a `char*` for the following function:

```
int fnc_ExtractYear(char* yyyymmdd)
{
    ...
}
```

**This function is from a DLL.**

I am using the `c_str()` function to convert the `"2022-07-10"` value to `char*`, but I am getting the following value:

`0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10"`

```
void __fastcall TfrmMain::btnExecuteClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    int year;
    TDate date;
    AnsiString strdate;
    const char* cdate;

    switch(rdgSelect->ItemIndex)
        {
        case  0 :
            date = dtpDate->Date; // Date (:TDate) = 10/07/2022
            // strDate (:AnsiString) = "2022-07-10"
            strdate = FormatDateTime("yyyy-mm-dd", date); 
            // cdate = 0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10" 
            cdate = strdate.c_str();
            year = fnc_ExtractYear(cdate);
            lblResult->Caption = IntToStr(year);
            break;
        ...
        }
```

The converted value to `char*` does not work.

The `int fnc_ExtractYear(char* yyyymmdd)` function returns `-1` as the year value instead of `2022` when I pass the `0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10"` value.

I need to get the converted value to `char*` as `"2022-07-10"` and not to `0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10"`.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you getting the value? Doesn't using the value work well? If it doesn't work, what happens?

Comment: Why you do conversion to string if you just need a year to be visualize? Just get year form `dtpDate->Date` directly: [see doc](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.DateUtils.YearOf). Do not make things to complicated.

Comment: Or just do `lblResult->Caption = FormatDateTime("yyyy", date);`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I am testing some functions exported from a dll. I need to test the int fnc_ExtractYear(char* yyyymmdd) function. That is why I need to convert the date string to char*.

Comment: `FormatDateTime()` will NOT give you `0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10"`, that looks like something the *debugger* would give you. `FormatDateTime()` will give you `"2022-07-10"` as requested. The code shown looks fine, so the real problem is likely in `fnc_ExtractYear()` itself instead (for instance, if you declare it using the wrong calling convention, ie using `__cdecl` when the DLL expects `__stdcall` instead). If you hard-code `fnc_ExtractYear("2022-07-10")`, does it work correctly? Are you SURE the function wants the hyphens? Have you tried using `"yyyymmdd"` for the format string?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, If I hard-code fnc_ExtractYear("2022-07-10"), the hard-coded value "2022-07-10" is changed to 0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10" inside the function.
I am using the __cdecl calling convention because InterBase recommends it. I am testing the some UDFs - user defined functions - to use with my InterBase 2020 database exported from a dll.

Comment: @IMeMine "*the hard-coded value `"2022-07-10"` is changed to `0x0000000003623480 "2022-07-10"` inside the function*" - That is physically impossible. The data can't change like that. I don't think you are looking at the right thing. Are you sure you are not just looking at what a *debugger* shows you? The `0x0000000003623480` part is likely just the *memory address* of the string literal. The actual data does not contain `0x0000000003623480`, only `2022-07-10`. Perhaps you should provide a screenshot of what you are actually seeing.

Comment: @IMeMine `c_str()` does NOT return `char*`, it returns `wchar_t*` if you are using `UnicodeString` which is what `FormatDateTime()` returns for example. You'll need to convert the `UnicodeString` to `AnsiString` and use the `c_str()` of that.

Answer (score 1):

The RTL has many functions that allow you to work with dates and strings. One easy way to get just the end of the date string would be to use [`AnsiRightStr()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/System.StrUtils.AnsiRightStr):

```
year = fnc_ExtractYear(AnsiRightStr(cdate, 10));
```

Comment: If you are going to go the RTL route, you may as well just use [`YearOf()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.YearOf) instead and forget converting the date to a string or even calling the DLL for this.